# Calling tracking JavaScript from AMP pages

Tags: javascript, amp-html

We are using in house tracking mechanism for our website. We use our tracking.js file on our all pages.

Every page sent some info in an js object to this script file which later send this information to our tracking application using spring controller.

Now as to move page faster we use some pages in AMP templates.
But this does not allow us to use tracking.js

We tried iframe tag but it does not allow to use http call (it only allow https calls)

Could you please suggest a way to do it as it very critical and we can not move to https right now for other limitation.

Thanks
Virendra Agarwal

Comment: Please, "JavaScript" is one word, not two.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use tracking.js with AMP as it is considered as an external library. It's written on their How It Works page that it won't allow author-written/3rd party JS:

> "One thing we realized early on is that many performance issues are
>   caused by the integration of multiple JavaScript libraries, tools,
>   embeds, etc. into a page. This isn’t saying that JavaScript
>   immediately leads to bad performance, but once arbitrary JavaScript is
>   in play, most bets are off because anything could happen at any time
>   and it is hard to make any type of performance guarantee. With this in
>   mind we made the tough decision that **AMP HTML documents would not
>   include any author-written JavaScript, nor any third-party scripts**."

Only the [components on this AMP example](https://ampbyexample.com/#components) can be used.

Comment: i check the page it uses very limited info to track. In our script we track almost 20 different parameters and number of validations are applied on them. The flow works like this: page create an object with all parameters assigned then it object is send to our script and it sent this data to URL. Example shows here does not include any detailed scenario like this so could you please suggest any other approach.

Answer (score 1):

As we worked with Google. We got it sorted.
You can add your API to AMP pages after validation by Google.
This API must be behind https and all calls should be validated by Google.
Google then will white list on AMP page and you can use that code in production.